# Readers-writers problem, I need to let in 5 readers per writer in the database

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, readerwriterlock

I need to let 5 readers per writer into the database if there's a writer waiting, otherwise, let every reader into the database

Debugging this is very difficult and every time I try anything, I end up with deadlocks everywhere.

Does anyone have a simple, pseudocode algorithm that does this?